# Avoid CORS filters in application.conf

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, vue.js, cors

Using Angularjs or vue need node .. and allow CORS requests like ReactJS does in conf file ?
Is there a way not to allow CORS filters on server ?

Answer (score -1):

Look at [this article](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-deal-with-cors-error-on-vue-cli-3-d78c024ce8d3).

In a nutshell, inside vue.config.js file add following lines:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // options...
  devServer: {
        proxy: 'https://mywebsite/',
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking at an answer for the backend, since ReactJS uses node .. the html/js files reside on a different server than the backend server.  So the backend server has to accept CORS/ allow origins from different sources.